Map key to interrupt Insert-mode completion
Often, insert-mode completion can take some time (e.g. <C-x><C-l> on a common prefix in your project). <C-c> interrupts this. I'd like to map another key to also have this interrupt behaviour, like so:
inoremap <C-k> <C-c>

However, it seems that on <C-k>, the mapping only gets processed after the completion finishes, contrary to <C-c>.
How can I make my mapping also interrupt insert mode completion?
Edit:
To clarify, the problem is not about detecting whether we are in completion-mode. This can be achieved with pumvisible() or complete_info(). The problem is that before the popup menu appears, that is, when vim is (slowly) scanning a completion, the mappings don't trigger until scanning completes, unlike <C-c> (defeating the purpose of mapping something to <C-c>), which immediately interrupts the scanning without waiting for scanning to finish.

A simple insert mode mapping can't work because triggering completion puts you in a special "submode", note the quotes, where your mappings won't work and that doesn't have its own prefixed *[nore]map commands.
Moreover, :help i_ctrl-k is a very useful command that you should probably not override.
The solution can be found under :help ins-completion-menu:
There are no special mappings for when the popup menu is visible.  However,
you can use an Insert mode mapping that checks the pumvisible() function to
do something different.  Example:
    :inoremap <Down> <C-R>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>C-N>" : "\<lt>Down>"<CR>

In your case:
inoremap <C-k> <C-R>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>C-c>" : "\<lt>C-k>"<CR>

which:

does <C-c> when you press <C-k> while the popup menu is visible,
does <C-k> otherwise, so there is no loss in functionality.


In fact, I read that part of the manual and attempted that previously. Unfortunately, it does not work, and the completion is not interrupted. I have also tried things like checking for complete_info(['mode']).mode, which didn't work either, which is why I ended up trying the most direct remap. The problem with the remappings is that none of them interrupts the completion, like <C-c>. You can see that if you try to initiate a very slow completion.
Logically, if even the simplest remap to <C-c> doesn't work, it would follow that a more complex solution like yours doesn't work either.

Yeah you are right and I'm afraid I misread your question. The popup menu is not there yet because the completion list is currently being built, therefore pumvisible() is not true-ish yet. In that context, <C-c> is the global Ctrl-C used to interrupt long commands and I don't think it can be "re"mapped easily.
